# CreateJS: How do you use MovieClip assets exported by Flash CC?

Tags: flash, movieclip, createjs

I'm exporting a bunch of assets with Flash CC HTML5 template for use in a project. There is one movieclip in the lib code but when I test I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'm loading movieclip-0.7.1.min.js but createjs doesn't find it? Question to the advanced CreateJS coders: How the heck do you use movieclip assets exported from the Flash IDE?? Is this even supposed to work? And if so how do you get createjs to make use of the loaded movieclip JS?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you what you used for your lib namespace. This can either be found on the last 2 lines of your output javascript file like the following. In this case, `lib_test` is the lib namespace:

```
})(lib_test = lib_test||{}, images = images||{}, createjs = createjs||{});
var lib_test, images, createjs;
```

You can also find/change this in the publish settings of the CreateJS Toolkit like this:

[image: CreateJS Toolkit Publish Settings]

Then, assuming your lib namespace is `lib_test`, create new instances of library items like this:

```
var symbol = new lib_test.Symbol1();
```